# Angular w/ Angular Material - Dialog theme broken

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

Hello i'm having an issue with Angular Material theme breaking in a Dialog Component, where the color of text and other components aren't working in the ways they should.

In app.component I have a setting icon button to open a dialog main.settings.dialog but when it opens as seen in the picture below the coloring is not fitting the Dark Theme.

Any insight as to why this isn't working in a normal way would be greatly appreciated as i can't find a way to fix this.

[Live example site](https://sendmix-9c2e2.firebaseapp.com/)

[Link to full source code](https://github.com/MSU-CSIT-Club/SendMix)

[image]

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Since you have your theme inside a style class, you need to add that to global overlay container.

Here is how, in your `AppModule`:

```
import {OverlayContainer} from '@angular/cdk/overlay';

@NgModule({
      // ...
})
export class AppModule {
      constructor(overlayContainer: OverlayContainer) {
          overlayContainer.getContainerElement().classList.add('app-dark-theme');
      }
}
```

Link to official documentation: https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#multiple-themes

---

**UPDATE:**
For dynamically changing the theme:

```
import { OverlayContainer } from '@angular/cdk/overlay';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {

constructor(
  private _overlayContainer: OverlayContainer
) { }

changeTheme(theme: 'app-theme-dark' | 'app-theme-light'): void {
  // remove old theme class and add new theme class
  const overlayContainerClasses = this._overlayContainer.getContainerElement().classList;
  const themeClassesToRemove = Array.from(overlayContainerClasses)
    .filter((item: string) => item.includes('app-theme-'));
  if (themeClassesToRemove.length) {
    overlayContainerClasses.remove(...themeClassesToRemove);
  }
  overlayContainerClasses.add(theme);
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but this worked thank you very much! I'll read over the documentation more to understand it a bit better :)

Comment: how would you dynamically change this?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in your `material2-app-theme.scss` theme file:

```
.app-dark-theme {
  @include angular-material-theme($dark-theme);
}
```

This is known as a mixin in Sass. When written this way, the theme would only apply to elements with the class `.app-dark-theme`.

Removing the class and just leaving:

```
@include mat-core();

$primary: mat-palette($mat-brown, 400);
$accent:  mat-palette($mat-yellow, 100);
$warn:    mat-palette($mat-deep-orange);
$dark-theme:   mat-dark-theme($primary, $accent, $warn);


@include angular-material-theme($dark-theme);
```

applies the theme to your whole app. By the looks of it, that means you can take out a hefty chunk of the css that's currently in there.

Also note: the first line in the dialog container isn't wrapped by any tags other than the parent `div` so there's no font styling applied to it. Material gives several convenience directives to help with dialog styling, e.g. `<h2 mat-dialog-title>Dialog Title!</h2>`