# Angular Material themes toggle not switching themes

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular-material, themes

**Scenario** 
We followed this [tutorial](https://medium.com/better-programming/angular-multiple-themes-without-killing-bundle-size-with-material-or-not-5a80849b6b34) to provide our users a dark and a light theme.

**Problem** 
The browser loads the expected css-File (dark or light). Nevertheless, the styles are not applied to our components.
This happens in `<head></head>`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme-dark.css">
```

or

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme-light.css">
```

As you can see, the browser correctly switches the two themes.

**Code** 
`angular.json`

```
"styles": [
          "projects/menu/src/styles.scss",
          {
            "input": "projects/menu/src/theming/theme-dark.scss",
            "bundleName": "theme-dark",
            "inject": false
          },
          {
            "input": "projects/menu/src/theming/theme-light.scss",
            "bundleName": "theme-light",
            "inject": false
          }
        ],
```

`theme-service.ts`

```
private _mainTheme$: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject(
    'theme-light'
);
private _darkMode$: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject(false);

darkMode$: Observable<boolean> = this._darkMode$.asObservable();

private _renderer: Renderer2;
private head: HTMLElement;
private themeLinks: HTMLElement[] = [];

theme$: Observable<[string, boolean]>;

constructor(
    rendererFactory: RendererFactory2,
    @Inject(DOCUMENT) document: Document
) {
    this.head = document.head;
    this._renderer = rendererFactory.createRenderer(null, null);
    this.theme$ = combineLatest([this._mainTheme$, this._darkMode$]);
    this.theme$.subscribe(async ([mainTheme, darkMode]) => {
        const cssExt = '.css';
        const cssFilename = darkMode
            ? 'theme-dark' + cssExt
            : mainTheme + cssExt;
        await this.loadCss(cssFilename);
        if (this.themeLinks.length == 2)
            this._renderer.removeChild(this.head, this.themeLinks.shift());
    });
}

setMainTheme(name: string) {
    this._mainTheme$.next(name);
}

setDarkMode(value: boolean) {
    this._darkMode$.next(value);
}

private async loadCss(filename: string) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        const linkEl: HTMLElement = this._renderer.createElement('link');
        this._renderer.setAttribute(linkEl, 'rel', 'stylesheet');
        this._renderer.setAttribute(linkEl, 'type', 'text/css');
        this._renderer.setAttribute(linkEl, 'href', filename);
        this._renderer.setProperty(linkEl, 'onload', resolve);
        this._renderer.appendChild(this.head, linkEl);
        this.themeLinks = [...this.themeLinks, linkEl];
    });
}
```

`theme-base.scss`

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';

@include mat-core();

@mixin theming($theme) {
  @include angular-material-theme($theme);
}
```

`theme-dark.scss`

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';
@import './theme-base';

@include mat-core();

// color palette definitions

$primary: mat-palette($dark-md-mcgpaletteblack);
$accent: mat-palette($md-mcgpalettewhite);
$warn: mat-palette($dark-md-mcgpalettered);
$background:mat-palette($dark-md-mcgpalettebackground);
$confirm: mat-palette($dark-md-mcgpaletteorange);

$theme-dark: mat-dark-theme((color: (primary: $primary,
  accent: $accent,
  warn: $warn,
  background: $background,
  confirm: $confirm)));
```

`theme-dark.scss` - looks the same

In `style.scss` we import both themes:

`styles.scss`

```
@import 'projects/menu/src/theming/theme-dark.scss';
@import 'projects/menu/src/theming/theme-light.scss';

.theme-dark {
  @include angular-material-theme($theme-dark)
}

.theme-light {
  @include angular-material-theme($theme-light)
}
```

and then we use those variables:

`styles.scss`

```
body {
  background: mat-color($background, default);
}

h1 {
   color: mat-color($accent, default);
}
```

**But currently we also import them in our components. I think this is one thing, that is wrong.** 
A dialog would look like this:

```
@import 'projects/menu/src/theming/theme-dark.scss';
@import 'projects/menu/src/theming/theme-light.scss';

.theme-dark {
  @include angular-material-theme($theme-dark)
}

.theme-light{
  @include angular-material-theme($theme-light)
}

.mat-button {
  color: mat-color($accent, default);
  background-color: mat-color($confirm, default);
}
```

**What I tried:**

- Removing the import of both themes in every stylesheet. Colors are still influenced by the order of the theme import in `style.scss`. Dark theme last -> dark theme will be used and the other way round.
- Using the same variables for the themes as in the tutorial. But then we had to change of all of the `background-color: mat-color($confirm, default);`
- And so on. Spent lots of time...

We can't figure out how to put the missing parts together. Do we need to use mixins? Or are we missing setting the class `dark-theme` on the root component?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## We finally got it working.

### Our mistakes:

- `@include mat-core();` must only be imported once (in  `theme-base.scss`)
- `@import 'projects/menu/src/theming/theme-dark.scss';` and `@import  'projects/menu/src/theming/theme-light.scss';` must only be imported once (in `styles.scss`). Importing them in all of the components lets bundle size explode.
- Set `theme-dark` class directly in `theme-dark.scss`
- Do not set classes `theme-dark` and `theme-light` in `styles.scss` or any other component theme
- Create two wrapper elements for whole application: `<div [ngClass]="{ 'theme-dark': darkMode$ | async }"> <div class="mat-app-background"> <router-outlet></router-outlet></div></div>`
- If components need to access the theme, use mixins (example shown below)
- In `theme-service.ts`, use `OverlayContainer` to apply styles to material dialogs as well (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48431919/11711692))

## Mixin example:

`settings-dialog.component.scss`

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';

@mixin settings-dialog-theme($theme) {
  .settings-dialog {
    @include mat-elevation(2);
    .mat-button {
      background-color: mat-color($confirm);
    }
  }
}
```

`settings-dialog.component.html`

```
<div mat-dialog-content class="settings-dialog"> Put your content here </div>
```

Create a component theme as described [here](https://medium.com/grensesnittet/dynamic-themes-in-angular-material-b6dc0c88dfd7) 
`component-themes.scss`

```
@import 'your-path/settings-dialog.component';
@mixin component-themes($theme) {
  @include settings-dialog-theme($theme);
}
```

Import it into your base theme file 
`theme-base.scss`

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';
@import './component-themes.scss';

@include mat-core();

@mixin theming($theme) {
    @include angular-material-theme($theme);
    @include component-themes($theme);
}
```